# How to get the name of a button by clicking on it?

Tags: python, py-telegram-bot-api

I am developing a telegram bot in the Python programming language using the telebot library (pyTelegramBotApi). At the moment when I'm making buttons, I decided to use InlineKeyboardMarkup. The following questions arise, how to get the name of this button by clicking on the button. I need to get the index of an item in the list by the name I need to get from the button name.

```
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)

def callback_query(call):

    if call.data == 'SUBCATEGORIES_BTN':

        sub_id = names.index(???) # Here I have to insert the name from the button name
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as a button 'name'.

The only value that is returned by Telgram is the `data` attribute (called `callback_data`) that you've provided on the button. The text the user sees on the button is not given.

---

The `data` is available as `call.data` as you're already using in your code.

---

For a complete exaxmple on how to use the InlineKeyboard, consider taking a look at the
[pyTelegramBotApi Inline Keyboard Example](https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/blob/2dad99ad959741271a8ba1d114f2e3e5e65ff086/examples/inline_keyboard_example.py#L17)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! In the end, I decided to use a different kind of buttons, namely ReplyKeyboardMarkup, which just sends its name to the chat. And from there I can already get it to a text processing event.
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])

Answer (score 0):

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])

def text(message):

```
if message.text = 'SUBCATEGORIES_BTN':

     sub_id = names.index(f'{message.text}')
```